# kill -9 does not kill nginx process in docker container

Tags: unix, nginx

I am trying to start nginx, when I try and start nginx, I get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

When I run `ps ax | grep nginx` I get:

```
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
 4042 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
 4063 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep nginx
```

When I try `kill -9 1` it does not error but running  `ps ax | grep nginx` gets the same response.

My `nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
worker_processes 1;

user nobody nogroup;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /tmp/logs/nginx.error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    accept_mutex off;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /tmp/logs/nginx.access.log combined;
    sendfile on;

    server {
        proxy_http_version 1.1; # this is essential for chunked responses to work

        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        server_name _;


        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types application/javascript text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location /cutting/  {
            alias /cutting/;
        }

        location  / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

            # UNCOMMENT LINE BELOW IF THIS IS BEHIND A SSL PROXY
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass   http://localhost:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Process 1 is **init** which you shouldn't kill anyway. You'd crash the system if it worked.

Comment: you did `--restart` for auto-restarting nginx container ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't `kill` nginx process. `kill` process that use your port. 
Call command `netstat -plnt` and see who use your port